# Count rows in another sheet and apply formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that has 2 sheets.
Sheet1 & Sheet2

Sheet1 will have a variable number of rows in it. In sheet2 i am looking to apply a formula in column "A" and apply it all the way down as applicable based on the number of rows present in Sheet1.

If i use the following code within the context of the same sheet then it works but i need to move this to another sheet.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=A2&""|""&B2&""|""&E2&""|""&G2"
End With
```

Comment: Change `"Sheet1"` to `"Sheet2"`, and then put `Sheets("Sheet1")` before `.Cells`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question out: Change `"Sheet1"` to `"Sheet2"`, and then put `Sheets("Sheet1")` before `.Cells` (and to be consistent, before `.Rows` too):

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("O2:O" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=A2&""|""&B2&""|""&E2&""|""&G2"
End With
```